# SAS Install Fails from not Finding libXext

Tags: java, linux, sas, rhel

I'm not sure if this is the correct part of the stackoverflow family to be posting this question to so I apologize if this isn't the correct site.

I'm trying to setup a new installation of SAS on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 on a 64-bit machine and I keep getting an error when attempting to run the setup.sh file included with SAS. In the terminal I receive the following:

```
An error occurred while launching Java. Please check the following log file:
/home/user/.SASAppData/SASDeploymentWizard/deploywiz_2013-12-15-23.41.42.log

/tmp/_setup21770/products/javaruntime__99185__lax__xx__sp0__1/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If I look at the error log I receive the following:

```
Sun Dec 15 23:16:36 EST 2013
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/_setup13184/products/javaruntime__99185__lax__xx__sp0__1/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraries(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.DebugHelper.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at com.sas.ssn.Kit.main(Kit.java:1653)
```

The strangest part is that I know libXtst (which from what I understand contains libXent) is installed properly. Running `locate libXtst` shows it in the following locations:

```
/usr/lib64/libXtst.so
/usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6
/usr/lib64/libXtst.so.6.1.0
```

and `yum list libXtst` returns `libXtst.x86_64 1.2.1-2.el6 @rhel-x86_64-server-6` as being installed.

I've Googled this pretty extensively and haven't come up with any reasonable solutions, even the previous admin's documentation on SAS installations didn't help here. I'd really appreciate a hand or pointer in the correct direction.

Edit: I forgot to include that if I run `setup.sh -console` I'm able to step through the text based installer.

Comment: `libXext`, not `libXtst`, but both should be installed by default on a generic Linux workstation. Check for the `libXext` package.

Comment: @chrylis Thanks for the quick comment. `Yum list libXext` shows `libXext.x86_64 1.3.1-2.el6 @rhel-x86_64-server-6` as installed.

Comment: If the suggestion @chrylis made doesn't work, I'd highly recommend putting in a ticket with [SAS support](http://support.sas.com).  They're pretty fast to respond and are pretty good with installation support.

Comment: @Joe this is true, I was trying to avoid it but they do have pretty great installation support. I'll give them a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're running a 32-bit JVM, and it can't link to the 64-bit system libraries; note the path `lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so`. You need to either run with a 64-bit JVM (the best option in any case) or install the 32-bit X libraries.

Comment: Wow, completely missed that, thank you. The part I'm confused about now is that `java -version` returns `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`. Any hints on why SAS might be looking for the i386 version when I haven't even specified whether I'm doing a 64-bit or 32-bit install?

Comment: The installer is different from 32 to 64 bit, at least on Windows - not sure on Linux.  IE, I can't do both 32 and 64 bit installs from the same installer.

Comment: @jak119 You'll notice that the path is buried somewhere in `/tmp`. My guess would be that SAS is including its own embedded 32-bit JRE.

Comment: @Joe You're correct, I was thinking of another installer but this is the correct 64-bit installer. I ended up contacting SAS Support who suggested installing libXext.i686 however that did not resolve the issue. I'll be sure to update when I hear back.

Comment: SAS Support replied and it turns out that SAS requires the i686 versions of libXext, libXtst, and libXp to be installed along with the 64-bit ones. @chrylis your reply was on the right track but the ultimate solution ended up being to install the 32-bit versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately ended up contact SAS support and it seems that the following 32-bit packages needed to be installed alongside their 64-bit counterparts for the installer to run:

- libXp.i686
- libXtst.i686
- libXext.i686

Once these packages were installed the installer ran without a problem.